# Sprite Kit declaration a local node

Tags: ios, variables, local, declaration

Which way is recommended for declare a local node?

(1) inside interface in the header file

```
@interface MyScene() <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *player;            

@end
```

(2) inside interface in the implementation file

```
@interface MyScene() 

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *player;            

@end
```

(3) inside implementation in the implementation file

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *_player;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the long answer you can read it [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/should-i-use-a-property-or-an-instance-variable/). if you prefer the short answer it is your third option: inside implementation in the implementation file.